# How can I make self sizing UITableViewCell with a UIStackView inside it

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uistackview

I can't achieve a self sizing `UITableViewCell` with a `UIStackView` inside it.

For the `UITableViewCell` I'm doing something like this:

[image: ui]

On code I'm doing this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 80
}
```

But when I run the app, the `UITableViewCell`s doesn't resizes:

[image: result]

What do I miss to make the `UITableViewCell` self sizing with a `UIStackView` inside it?

Comment: FWIW the `distribution` property is important. Sometimes you get unexpected results if you don't set it right.

Answer (score 3):

The cell resizing is working fine. Your problem is that you set a fixed height for the Stack View.

The View in the horizontal Stack View has its `height` set to `64`, most likely with its standard priority set to `1000`. This Stack View most likely has its distribution set to `Fill`. You basically told the Stack View that the containing image has to exactly fill the Stack View with a height of `64`. This is also limiting the Stack View to `64` and with it the vertical Stack View besides the View. Change the distribution of the horizontal Stack View that contains the View to `Center` if you want the vertical Stack View next to the View to get bigger than `64`.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have multi line labels?  If so make sure you have the lines property in IB set to 0 not 1.

Pin top and bottoms of stackView.

If that doesn't do it,  check these:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

Comment: I added the pins before, it shows on the image I added on the question. I added the two delegate methods and still don't working

Answer (score 1):

The trick to getting Auto Layout for self sizing cells to work on a UITableViewCell is to ensure you have constraints to pin each subview on all sides — that is, each subview should have leading, top, trailing and bottom constraints. Then, the intrinsic height of the subviews will be used to dictate the height of each cell.

Here is [a nice tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/129059/self-sizing-table-view-cells) that will get you through it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have all the pins (leading, top, trailing and bottom) but I am using a `UIStackView` and it has all the labels. The problem is the content of the `UIStackView` doesn't resize automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Try pinning the stack view itself. Remember the stackView has the responsibility to equally space, evenly distribute, etc., so it needs to use constraints between itself and its superView to figure all that out.

Here's an [apple explanation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/LayoutUsingStackViews.html).

HTH

Comment: Which contraints I need to set between itself and its superView?

Comment: I added equal widths the `UIStackView` to the `UITableViewCell`, now the `UIStackView` resizes but the `UITableViewCell` does not resize

Answer (score 0):

```
open class IntrinsicHeightTableView: UITableView {

open override var contentSize: CGSize {
    didSet { invalidateIntrinsicContentSize() }
}

open override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
    layoutIfNeeded()
    return CGSize(width: UIView.noIntrinsicMetric, height: contentSize.height)
} }
```